# How to disable TECH_DISCOVERED on the app?

Tags: android, android-manifest, deeplink

I used `DeepLink` to launch my application after detecting a certain url address from `NFC` like this.

```
        <activity
            android:name=".view.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
```

However, it works even when I already launched my application. So, duplicate activities keep coming up. And sometimes, it leads my app to **malfunction or crash**. I just want to use `Deeplink` while I am not using my application.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `launchMode="singleTop"`. This way, if the activity already is launched and is on the top of the stack, any new launches would be routed through this instance and you would get this as a callback in the `onNewIntent()` method.

```
<activity android:name=".view.main.MainActivity" 
          android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems work. But when `MainActivity` has other Fragments(not the first one), It acts the same. What should I do? I just have one Activity(MainActivity) and it contains many Fragments.

Comment: You have onNewIntent() which is called every time a new intent is fired. So from there you can choose to pass on info to your fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Dinesh's solution seems like it should work, but if it's giving you problems, you can try an alternative (more complicated) one. You can use the `NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()` method to take control of the `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` action inside your activity and make sure it does nothing.

You can that by adding the following two methods to your `MainActivity` (or adding the code to existing ones):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //create a broadcast intent that doesn't trigger anything
    Intent localIntent = new Intent("fake.action");
    localIntent.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);

    //set the NFC adapter to trigger our broadcast intent
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(
            this,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, localIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT),
            new IntentFilter[] {new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)},
            new String[][] { { "android.nfc.tech.IsoDep" /* add other tag types as necessary */ } });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```

Now whenever your activity is visible and an NFC tag is detected, no action will be triggered. (Or, more specifically, it will trigger a broadcast to which no method is registered.)

Hope this helps.